# Active Batch 9 - TSQLBlock OutputResults not working

Tags: sql-server-2008

We are using Active Batch 9 with Windows Server 2008 schedulers. Our database is SQL Server 2008 R2.

In our TSQLBlock tasks we specify OutputResults = True. The stored procedures we use emit multiple messages, but we don't see any of these messages in the task logs.

Has anyone gotten OutputResults to work? I suspect this is a configuration issue but am not sure where to look.